# How do I create an apple script that changes the destination folder of airdropped files?

Tags: macos, applescript, airdrop

I've [downloaded the following apple script](https://gist.github.com/menushka/cb3ed28b73fc030b5b21e0316d059928), which moves airdropped files to a specified folder (which I'll refer to as the Airdrop folder):

```
property AIRDROP_FOLDER : "Macintosh HD:Users:pschorn:Airdrop"
property QUARANTINE_KEY : "59"

property GET_QUARANTINE_COMMAND_START : "ls -l -@ '"
property GET_QUARANTINE_COMMAND_END : "' | tr '\\n' ' ' | sed 's/.*com\\.apple\\.quarantine\\s*\\(\\d*\\)/ \\1/' | awk '{$1=$1};1'"

on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving added_items
    repeat with i from 1 to length of added_items
        set current_item to item i of added_items
        set quarantine_type to getQuarantineType(POSIX path of current_item)
        if quarantine_type is equal to QUARANTINE_KEY then
            moveFile(current_item, alias AIRDROP_FOLDER)
        end if
    end repeat
end adding folder items to

on moveFile(move_file, destination_dir)
    tell application "Finder"
        move move_file to destination_dir with replacing
    end tell
end moveFile

on getQuarantineType(file_path)
    return do shell script GET_QUARANTINE_COMMAND_START & file_path & GET_QUARANTINE_COMMAND_END
end getQuarantineType
```

I followed the instructions on this [website](https://www.idownloadblog.com/2017/03/03/change-airdrop-destination-folder-mac/) to set it up as a folder actions script.

**However, if I move an airdropped file out of my newly created airdrop folder and back into my downloads folder, it gets automatically put BACK in the airdrop folder.** I don't want this to happen.

I found that after applying this terminal command `xattr -d com.apple.quarantine [file path of airdropped file]`, the file will no longer get moved back into my airdrop folder after I move it out.

**MY question is: How do I integrate this command into the above apple script so that the airdropped files do not automatically get moved back to my airdrop folder after I move them out of it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure of the provenance of the AirDropped files and are happy to remove the quarantine extended attribute you can remove it as you say with `xattr`.  In AppleScript you can do this using **do shell script** and passing the quoted path in alias form.

```
removeQuarantine(quoted form of (POSIX path of (current_item as alias)))
```

```
on removeQuarantine(file_path_alias)
    do shell script "xattr -d com.apple.quarantine " & file_path_alias
end removeQuarantine
```

In your script you want to call this *before* the file is moved so your script would look as below (remember to update the `AIRDROP_FOLDER` to your required path).

The script will now check files for `com.apple.quarantine` equal to 59 and if so remove the attribute before moving the file.

Therefore if you then move the file back to *~/Downloads* it will not be moved again as the `com.apple.quarantine` attribute is no longer there.

---

```
property AIRDROP_FOLDER : "macOS:Users:hali:Desktop:Test"
property QUARANTINE_KEY : "59"

property GET_QUARANTINE_COMMAND_START : "ls -l -@ '"
property GET_QUARANTINE_COMMAND_END : "' | tr '\\n' ' ' | sed 's/.*com\\.apple\\.quarantine\\s*\\(\\d*\\)/ \\1/' | awk '{$1=$1};1'"

on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving added_items
    repeat with i from 1 to length of added_items
        set current_item to item i of added_items
        set quarantine_type to getQuarantineType(POSIX path of current_item)
        if quarantine_type is equal to QUARANTINE_KEY then
            removeQuarantine(quoted form of (POSIX path of (current_item as alias)))
            moveFile(current_item, alias AIRDROP_FOLDER)
        end if
    end repeat
end adding folder items to

on moveFile(move_file, destination_dir)
    tell application "Finder"
        move move_file to destination_dir with replacing
    end tell
end moveFile

on getQuarantineType(file_path)
    return do shell script GET_QUARANTINE_COMMAND_START & file_path & GET_QUARANTINE_COMMAND_END
end getQuarantineType

on removeQuarantine(file_path_alias)
    do shell script "xattr -d com.apple.quarantine " & file_path_alias
end removeQuarantine
```

---

**Note** : This script will overwrite files of the same name in the destination without prompting.  If this is a concern there is a forked version by user SuraAzure on [github](https://gist.github.com/SoraAzure/0f56a11133c4b577ad35184b99434d0a) that appends a sequence number to the filename before moving if a file with the same name already exists in the destination directory.